# numpy array shape doesn't match subarrays'

Tags: python, dataframe, numpy, reshape, numpy-ndarray

To train a neural network, I have used images to create array through a `pandas` dataframe, but the original shape does not match the shape of the subarray.

The dataframe `data`:

```
    FilePaths   Labels
0   [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,...   Hourse Mackerel
1   [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,...   Gilt-Head Bream
2   [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,...   Gilt-Head Bream
3   [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,...   Gilt-Head Bream
4   [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,...   Red Mullet
... ... ...
8995    [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,...   Red Sea Bream
8996    [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,...   Black Sea Sprat
8997    [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,...   Red Mullet
8998    [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,...   Sea Bass
8999    [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,...   Hourse Mackerel
```

I turned it into a tuple `fish_data` with one array for data and one for labels. I also converted the labels into numbers.

```
change = {'Black Sea Sprat':0, 'Gilt-Head Bream':1, 'Hourse Mackerel':2, 'Red Mullet':3, 'Red Sea Bream':4, 'Sea Bass':5, 'Shrimp':6, 'Striped Red Mullet':7, 'Trout':8}
fish_data = np.array(data.FilePaths), np.array(data.Labels)
for i, v in enumerate(fish_data[1]):
    fish_data[1][i] = np.uint8(change[v])
```

Then I split the data into training and testing portions:

```
(x_train, y_train), (x_test,y_test) = (fish_data[0][:8100], fish_data[1][:8100]), (fish_data[0][:8100], fish_data[1][:8100])
```

Now, when I check `x_train.shape`, it's: `(8100,)`

But when I check `x_train[0].shape`, it returns`(445, 590)`

I expected `x_train.shape` to be `(8100, 445, 590)`

Can anyone tell me why this is happening and how to fix it?

(Edit)
`type(x_train)` and `type(x_train[0])` and `type(x_train[0][0])` are all  `np.ndarray`

Comment: What does `np.stack(x_train)` do?

Comment: from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split                                               
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.20, random_state=27)

Comment: Tbe dataframe has one 2d array in each cell of that column.  `np.array(data.FilePaths)`, aka `data.FilePaths.to_numpy()` returns a like structured array, 1d object dtype. Isn't there something in pandas docs about such frames?

Comment: @hpaulj Turns out it was just `numpy` reading the arrays within the array as objects instead of as 1 array. fixed with `np.concatenate()` and a little reshaping